# openni_kinect lauching error

Tags: kinect, pcl, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The openni_kinect driver worked well on my computer, with Diamondback and Ubuntu 10.04 x64.
But now when I try to start it, it gives an error, which is the same as in this thread
[openni launching errors](http://answers.ros.org/question/192/openni-launching-errors)

None of the solutions could solve the problem for me.

Before the error appears, I cleaned and reinstalled perception_pcl stack and perception_pcl_addons stack. Not sure if this is related to the error.(I did rosmake openni_kinect and openni_camera)

Here is the output

```
... logging to /home/vincent/.ros/log/093add86-a0ee-11e0-93c2-d4856407c2d5/roslaunch-vincent-desktop-1308.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://vincent-desktop:43042/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [1322]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 093add86-a0ee-11e0-93c2-d4856407c2d5
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [1335]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [1347]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [1348]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [1349]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [1350]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [1357]
[ INFO] [1309200506.146912253]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1309200506.147098848]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:19 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00366A18480046A'
[ INFO] [1309200506.151439147]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1309200506.225302725]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:19 with serial number 'A00366A18480046A'
[ INFO] [1309200506.260280871]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1309200506.265424478]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame' 
[openni_node1-2] process has died [pid 1347, exit code -11].
log files: /home/vincent/.ros/log/093add86-a0ee-11e0-93c2-d4856407c2d5/openni_node1-2*.log
```

The log file says

```
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:24,344] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] UDPROS server listening on port [45680]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:24,354] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] Started node [/openni_node1], pid [1347], bound on [vincent-desktop], xmlrpc port [59629], tcpros port [46407], logging to [/home/vincent/.ros/log/093add86-a0ee-11e0-93c2-d4856407c2d5/openni_node1-2.log], using [real] time
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:24,364] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/openni_node1/num_worker_threads] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:24,596] [thread 0x7feb017e9700]: [DEBUG] Accepted connection on socket [7], new socket [16]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:24,597] [thread 0x7feb017e9700]: [DEBUG] TCPROS received a connection from [127.0.1.1:51450]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:24,597] [thread 0x7feb017e9700]: [DEBUG] Connection: Creating TransportSubscriberLink for topic [/rosout] connected to [callerid=[/rosout] address=[TCPROS connection to [127.0.1.1:51450 on socket 16]]]
[ros.openni_camera./openni_node1] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,146] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [INFO] [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ros.openni_camera./openni_node1] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,147] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [INFO] [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:19 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00366A18480046A'
[ros.openni_camera./openni_node1] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,151] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [INFO] [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ros.openni_camera./openni_node1] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,225] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [INFO] [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:19 with serial number 'A00366A18480046A'
[ros.openni_camera./openni_node1] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,260] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [INFO] rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ros.openni_camera./openni_node1] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,265] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [INFO] depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame' 
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,424] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/format] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,427] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/jpeg_quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,429] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/png_level] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,472] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/optimize_for] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,474] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/target_bitrate] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,476] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,478] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/keyframe_frequency] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,504] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/format] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,506] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/jpeg_quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,509] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/png_level] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,533] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/optimize_for] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,536] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/target_bitrate] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,538] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,541] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/keyframe_frequency] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,565] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/format] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,568] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/jpeg_quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,570] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/png_level] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,595] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/optimize_for] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,597] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/target_bitrate] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,600] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,602] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/keyframe_frequency] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,627] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/compressed/format] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,629] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/compressed/jpeg_quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,632] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/compressed/png_level] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,656] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/theora/optimize_for] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,659] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/theora/target_bitrate] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,661] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/theora/quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,664] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image/theora/keyframe_frequency] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,689] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/format] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,691] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/jpeg_quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,694] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/png_level] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,719] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/optimize_for] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,721] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/target_bitrate] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,724] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/quality] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-06-27 15:48:26,726] [thread 0x7feb0e4e47c0]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/keyframe_frequency] is not set]
```

Is this a known bug, has anyone come across the same situation?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10309/openni_kinect-lauching-error/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-06-29**:
did you install it from source? I'm just guessing but you could try to install by "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect"... then don't rosmake it and just run "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes I installed it from source.

Not sure why, but "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect" did the trick.

Thanks guys!

---

Originally posted by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) with karma: 311 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your error is different than the ones in the other thread. The looked more like hardware problems.

I looks as something is misconfigured somehow. As far as I know the params that are accessed (producing the errors) are the ones that you can dynamic_reconfigure for the image streams. My guess is something there went wrong.

A quick grep revealed they aren't directly in the node code. I can't check more from here.
You could search for them yourself or wait for someone who knows where they should have been configured.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1